# htaccess redirect to https (in some cases)

Tags: .htaccess, https

how can i create directive in .htaccess that will redirect me to specific port (on same url), if url is https?

ie. i have https://mysite.com/file.php:8080, it shoud redirect me to https://mysite.comfile.php:8088

or

http://mysite.com/file.php:8080, it shoud redirect me to https://mysite.comfile.php:8088

so, it have to redirect me to https and port 8088

thank you in advance on your help!

Answer (score 0):

what u r asking has to be done through apache configuration(httpd.conf) not through htaccess..
you need to have ssl certifate for your server..